# Getting a field from document via mongoengine

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a places collection, from which i was trying to extract the place names to suggest to the user, but it's taking much time, would like to know if there are any ways to optimize. I use mongoengine ORM and the database is mongodb.

query:

```
results = Place.objects(name__istartswith=query).only('name')
```

the query takes very less time in the matter of microseconds.

but now when i try to access the names from results

```
names = [result.name for result in results]
```

this line takes a very long time, varies from 3-5 secs, for a list of length around 2500.

I have tried using `scalar`, but now the time increases when i do an union over another list.

Is there a better way to access the names list.

Answer (score 0):

A queryset isn't actioned until its iterated so `results = Place.objects(name=query).only('name')` returns a queryset that hasn't been called yet.  When you iterate it the query takes place and data is sent over the wire.

Is the query slow when running via pymongo?  As you don't need them as MongoEngine objects try using [as_pymongo](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=as_pymongo#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.as_pymongo) - which returns raw dictionaries back.

Other hints are to make sure the query is performant - using an index - see the [profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) docs.

Comment: acutally its the problem with regex matching, i am using Place.object(name__istartswith) , and have an index on the field "name", i was reading some docs on mongodb, and they say it's slow because of this regex. I have changed the same in the original question